# Ubuntu 17.10: Disable user list in GDM

Tags: 17.10, gdm

I have the following system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:        17.10
Codename:       artful

$ gdm3 --version
GDM 3.26.1
```

I would like to disable the user list in GDM and enter my user name and password to log-in. I have already searched a lot but did not find any valuable solution.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**This feature is currently bugged, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724944 and mark yourself affected**

You need to install the `dconf-editor` tool if you not have already:

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

Then when you opened it navigate to:

```
/org/gnome/login-screen
```

and set the 'disable-user-list' button to 'on':

[image]

---

Since the above is still bugged, the only solution is right now via terminal edit the following lines in `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`:

```
#[org/gnome/login-screen]
# disable-user-list=true
```

to:

```
[org/gnome/login-screen]
disable-user-list=true
```

Be sure to edit both lines otherwise you might crash your login completely.

Comment: Bug has a solution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724944/comments/7 for 17.04 and 17.10.  For 18.04 you also need to uncomment `[org/gnome/login-screen]` if you do it your way. Only doing your uncomment crashes the login.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for that information, incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One option:

Edit `/usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults` and remove "#" to uncomment the line:

```
disable-user-list=true
```

Another option:

Use gconftool-2 or gconf-editor. Change this value to true:

```
/apps/gdm/simple-greeter/disable_user_list
```

#### Reference

https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/stable/configuration.html.en
https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2016/05/28/gnome-3-customizing-the-login-screen/#userlist

Comment: See comment made at the other post.  You also need to uncomment `[org/gnome/login-screen]` if you do it your way. Only doing your uncomment crashes the login.